# jqxDropDownList Filter on Part of String

Tags: filtering, jqxwidgets

When jqxDropDownList, is there a way to enable filtering on any word in string. For example, if a value in the list is John Smith, I would like to be able to type "Smith" in the filter text and find this one.

I am setting the filterable setting to true, is there something else I can do to enable partial string filtering?

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the javascript for the control, there are several settings that are not in the documentation, one of them is `searchMode`, which has values of:

- `containsignorecase`
- `contains`
- `equals`
- `equalsignorecase`
- `startswith`
- `startswithignorecase`
- `endswith`
- `endswithignorecase`

An example would be:

```js
$("#jqxProductList").jqxDropDownList({
    filterable: true,
    searchMode: "containsignorecase",
    checkboxes: true,
    source: dataAdapter,
    displayMember: "model",
    valueMember: "product",
    width: 400,
    height: 25
});
```